# Scraping Pods of a Specific Availability Zone using Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator

I want to scrape Pods of a Specific Availability Zone but the Availability Zone label is only present on the node not on the pods.
[prometheus-doc screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTS2t.png)
I have read a [prometheus document](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#kubernetes_sd_config)
In which they are saying:
we can attache node metadata to discovered targets. Valid for roles: pod, endpoints, endpointslice.

here is my config :

```
- job_name: 'istio-monitoring'
      scrape_interval: 10s
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: pod
        namespaces:
          names:
          - integration
          - istio-system
        attach_metadata:
          node: true 
        selectors:
        - role: "node"
          label: "az=us-east-1"
```

But this is not working and getting error:
level=error msg="Error loading config (--config.file=/etc/prometheus/config_out/prometheus.env.yaml)" file=/etc/prometheus/config_out/prometheus.env.yaml err="parsing YAML file /etc/prometheus/config_out/prometheus.env.yaml: pod role supports only pod selectors"

Comment: What Prometheus version do you use?